Inplace upgrade of CloudLinux7.9 to CloudLinux8 with plesk obsidian 18.0.52
In our environment we are using CloudLinux 7.9 as OS and on top of it we have hosted plesk obsidian 18.0.52 . Since EOL is near we would like to migrate or perform inplace upgrade of CloudLinux8.
When we checked with CloudLinux they said only for Cpanel/no panel for now they have come up the feature of supporting inplace upgrade from CloudLinux 7 to 8 . But for plesk is not supported yet.
Any suggestions of idea how to perform this upgrade or anyone already tried ? Kindly advise
"We have tried to setup new server with CloudLinux 8 with plesk it works or we have option to perform upgrade or migration form Centos7 with plesk to Almalinux8 it works . But with cloudLinux7 to 8 we are stuck ."
